# Velocity.js not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, modernizr, velocity.js

I'm trying to include a JavaScript fallback for Microsoft Internet Explorer 8 for a CSS3 based animation using Velocity.js and Modernizr. This is the site I'm working on (it's a case study on crossbrowser compatibility).

http://bit.ly/1G03UMo

This is how I've done it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Modernizr.load([{
        test: Modernizr.csstransforms && Modernizr.csstransforms3d && Modernizr.cssanimations,
        nope: ['http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.min.js', 'js/animatie.js']
    }]);
</script>
```

The Modernizr tests (csstransforms, csstransforms3d and cssanimations) all return a logical answer - 'no-xxx' in IE. The files mentioned in the nope array all load in that case.

The contents of the animatie.js file are as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div#tandwiel').velocity({
        rotateZ: '360deg'
    },
    {
        duration: 10000,
        easing: 'linear',
        loop: true
    });
});
```

I am pretty sure the jQuery code is right, since outputting to the console yields predictable results. I am also pretty sure Velocity.js is loaded, since animating a dull property like opacity actually does work in every browser.

In the Velocity.js documentation I found that it doesn't actually need jQuery to perform its magic, but it should be included for it to work in IE8.

Things I sort of ruled out.

- It hardly can't be a syntax error. Checked thrice.
- It doesn't have anything to do with load order. jQuery seems to be loaded when the animatie.js file is loaded. The yepnope library also honors the order of the files mentioned.
- It can't be Velocity.js, since the author is way smarter than I am and there aren't many complaints it doesn't work in IE8.

(I know, a spinning gear isn't going to make or break the user experience, but I would like to know what is going on here).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> SCRIPT5022: Velocity: IE8 and below require jQuery to be loaded before Velocity.
>   File: velocity.min.js, Line: 3, Column: 9801

This is shown in the console of ie8 when opening the link in the question.
Have you tried loading jquery via modernizr?

```
    Modernizr.load([{
        test: Modernizr.csstransforms && Modernizr.csstransforms3d && Modernizr.cssanimations,
        nope: ['http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.min.js', 'js/animatie.js'],
        both: ['http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js']
    }]);
```